# Domain with failback IP

Tags: dns, high-availability

I want to mount a system with 2 dedicated servers with different providers. My main interest is to have some high availability. The use case is the following:

We have a domain pointing out to a public IP. When the server on that IP shutdown we want to change the IP to another server that has the same resources. We know that we can change the dns configuration (in the administration panel of our domain provider), but it must be a manual configuration where somebody must connect to the administration panel and change it, furthermore wait to the dns propagation.

Is there any possible solution to have an automatic failover IP doing that automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Amazon Route 53 DNS health checks and failover functionality. I guess it suits your needs, but you have to switch your domains nameservers or at least a subdomains nameserver to Amazon:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html